# Scrap web content from Amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape Amazon prices with phantomjs and python. I want to parse it with beautiful soup, to get the new and used prices for books, the problem is: when I pass the source of the request I do with phantomjs the prices are just 0,00, the code is this simple test.

I don't understand if is amazon who have measures to avoid scraping prices or I'm doing it wrong because I was trying with other more simple pages and I can get the data I want.

PD I'm in a country not supported to use amazon API, that's why the scraper is necesary

```
import re
import urlparse

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

link = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/1119998956/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new'#'http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1119998956'

class AmzonScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

    def scrape_prices(self):
        self.driver.get(link)
        s = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source)
        return s

    def scrape(self):
        source = self.scrape_prices()
        print source
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = TaleoJobScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

Comment: Just FYI, you should not SAY you are doing this, it's against Amazon's ToS, you could get in big trouble.

Comment: where are you scraping anything?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah, clearly this is completely unrelated to web-scraping. And the class name is `AmzonScraper`, so it's about `Amzon` store - a completely different web store.

Comment: @alecxe, `TaleoJobScraper()` is nowhere to be seen in the code and all I see the OP's code doing is downloading the html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to follow @Nick Bailey's comment, *study the Terms of Use* and make sure there are no violations on your side.

To solve it, you need to *tweak `PhantomJS` desired capabilities*:

```
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
caps["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"

self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=caps)
self.driver.maximize_window()
```

---

And, to make it *bullet-proof*, you can make a [Custom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848) [Expected Condition](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) and *wait for the price to become non-zero*:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_price(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try :
            element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text.strip()
            return element_text != "0,00"
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Usage:

```
def scrape_prices(self):
    self.driver.get(link)

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 200).until(wait_for_price((By.CLASS_NAME, "olpOfferPrice")))
    s = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source)

    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

Good answer on setting the user agent for phantomjs to that of a normal browser.  Since you said that your country is being blocked by amazon, then I would imagine that you also need to set a proxy.

here is an example of how to start phantomJS in python with a firefox useragent and a proxy.

```
from selenium.webdriver import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
service_args = [ '--proxy=1.1.1.1:port', '--proxy-auth=username:pass'  ]
dcap = dict( DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS )
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
driver = PhantomJS( desired_capabilities = dcap, service_args=service_args )
```

where 1.1.1.1 is your proxy ip and port is the proxy port.  Also username and password are only necessary if your proxy requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Another framework to try is [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) it is simpler than selenium, which is used to simulate browser interactions. Scrapy gives you classes for easily parsing data using `CSS selectors` or `XPath`, and a pipeline to store that data in whatever format you'd like, like writing it to a `MongoDB` database for example

Often times you can write a fully build spider and deploy it to the Scrapy cloud in **under 10 lines of code**

Checkout this YT video on how to use Scrapy for [scraping Amazon reviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnEsG3Kaz6A) as a use case