# Selenium - upload file to iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, upload

I have a test which has method to upload file in form located in `iframe`.

The problem is that test not stable and sometimes fails with the error (run three times to get error example, third run failed):

```
def fill_offer_image(self):
    driver = self.app.driver
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_name("upload_iframe")[3])
E       IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have `implicitly wait = 10` and as you can consider few iframes on the page with the same class so I've been forced to use arrays. And sometimes not all (or all?) iframes loaded.

Does someone have thoughts how to improve stability of that test?
Could it relate to mechanics of iframe itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this by giving some time for iframe to load by inserting the below code

```
Import time

## Give time for iframe to load ##
time.sleep(xxx)
```

hope this will work

Comment: Thanks, Shaik, your way worked perfect on few tests.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) and *wait until the count of frame elements with `name="upload_iframe"` becomes 4* by writing a [custom expected condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_n_elements(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, count):
        self.locator = locator
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            count = len(EC._find_elements(driver, self.locator))
            return count == self.count
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Usage:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(wait_for_n_elements((By.NAME, 'upload_iframe'), 4))

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_name("upload_iframe")[3])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, alecxe.
Tried your advice and faced with the timeout excepition  

`>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:75: TimeoutException`
Think it's by the reason of implicitly and explicit waits.  
Tried to play with imply (5, 10, 15 seconds) but got same result.
May be there are the way to force exact method ignore global implicitly wait?

Comment: I tried to play with implicitly wait inside method but without result. Alecxe, thanks for you note about such interesting way as waiting for elements.