# Python selenium click element while displayed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm scraping a dynamic page that requires the user to click a "Load More Results" button several times in order to get all data. Is there a better way to approach the task of clicking on an element while displayed?

```
def clickon(xpath):
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except:
        print "RETRYING CLICKON() for %s" % (xpath)
        time.sleep(1)
        clickon(xpath)
    else:
        element.click()
        time.sleep(3)

def click_element_while_displayed(xpath):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    try:
        while element.is_displayed():
            clickon(xpath)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are asking this question because the current solution is slow. This is mostly because you have these hardcoded `time.sleep()` delays which wait for more than they usually should. To tackle this problem I'd start using [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) - initialize an endless loop and break it once selenium stopped waiting for the button to be clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
   try:
       element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
       element.click()
   except TimeoutException:
       break  # cannot click the button anymore

   # TODO: wait for the results of the click action
```

Now the last `TODO` part is also important - here I suggest you wait for a specific condition that would indicate that click resulted into something on a page - for instance, more results were loaded. For example, you can use a custom Expected Condition similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177865/771848).