# How to parse Selenium driver elements?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new in Selenium with Python. I'm trying to scrape some data but I can't figure out how to parse outputs from commands like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.flightbox")
```

I was trying to google some tutorial but I've found nothing for Python.

Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find_elements_by_css_selector()` would return you a *list of [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) instances*. Each web element has a number of methods and attributes available. For example, to get an inner text of the element, use `.text`:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.flightbox"):
    print(element.text)
```

You can also make a context-specific search to find other elements inside the current element. Taking into account, that [I know what site you are working with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942041/slow-scrolling-down-the-page-using-selenium/30942319#30942319), here is an example code to get the departure and arrival times for the first-way flight in a result box:

```
for result in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.flightbox"):
    departure_time = result.find_element_by_css_selector("div.departure p.p05 strong").text
    arrival_time = result.find_element_by_css_selector("div.arrival p.p05 strong").text

    print [departure_time, arrival_time]
```

---

Make sure you study [Getting Started](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html), [Navigating](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html) and [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) documentation pages.

Comment: @Milan you are welcome. See if we can "close" the previous topic too. Happy parsing :)

Comment: Hi @Alecxe, could I ask if you could take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832771/python-and-selenium-extract-the-information-in-a-div-class-to-a-json-object-or; I tried your suggestion in 'Update 5' of my question (I'm trying different approaches, but still struggling), if you had the time, I would appreciate it.