# How to parse the page once the onclick element is executed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver to click on the javascript onclick element. Once it is clicked, I want to parse the content of clicked element using BeautifulSoup. Here is my code to click the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://www.mobikwik.com/'
driver.get(url)
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".check-plans.ng-scope")
el.click()
```

Now I want to further parse the plans which I can see. How can I do this?

Comment: So, if you want to parse content with `BeautifulSoup`, then import it and use appropriately. What's the problem? Can you describe specific issue you encountered?

Comment: select the element you want to get. after the click()

Answer (score 0):

If you feed the html of the page that driver loaded from the driver into beautiful soup you can then navigate it as a parsed page.  Find the element you are looking for again with a [soup.find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) and then you can navigate it accordingly.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(el.text, 'html5lib')`

Look [here for reference to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945212/how-to-parse-selenium-driver-elements).