# Python Selenium Wait till Any Text

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I have a selenium test which need to wait till any text to be populated instead an exact text string match...

I have learned that `text_to_be_present_in_element`, `text_to_be_present_in_element_value` can be used for this type of purpose but I might need something like regular expression instead of exact match.

Can anyone share is it possible?

```
# exact match.
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.Id,'f_name'), '<searchstring>'))
```

Comment: **Is there a way to do it without creating a custom EC, maybe something like: `wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//header/section//*[1]/button[.//*[contains(text(), "Follow") or contains(text(), "Follow Back") or contains(text(), "Message")]]'), ["Follow", "Follow Back", "Message"]'))` ???** (This is the actualy XPath btw)

Answer (score 3):

No problem. Make a [custom Expected Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848):

```
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_text_to_match(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, pattern):
        self.locator = locator
        self.pattern = re.compile(pattern)

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text
            return self.pattern.search(element_text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Usage:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(wait_for_text_to_match((By.ID, "myid"), r"regex here"))
```

Comment: **Is there a way to do it without creating a custom EC, maybe something like: `wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//header/section//*[1]/button[.//*[contains(text(), "Follow") or contains(text(), "Follow Back") or contains(text(), "Message")]]'), ["Follow", "Follow Back", "Message"]'))` ???** (This is the actualy XPath btw)