# Wait for not equal value [Selenium]

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I have done a lot of searching but can't seem to make Selenium wait for an id to NOT have a certain value. Some things I have tried:

This times out:

```
wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "price"), not " $0.00"))
```

This throws `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`:

```
wait.until(not EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "price"), " $0.00"))
```

This throws `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found`:

```
wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "price"), not " $0.00"))
```

Note:

- This it the only value in the price ID
- `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)`

Bonus Answer:

The entire issue is that the price starts at " $0.00" then changes to multiple elements which displays a loading gif. Finally, it would display the actual price. To finish my task I used the accepted answer below (until_not) to check that the 0 has become the gif, and an until with a custom function to check the regex not to match "$0". I used the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370850/7255697) with the regex pattern of "\$(?!0)\w".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` has another method `until_not` which inverts the expectation

EDIT: Try:

```
wait.until_not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "price"), " $0.00"))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14992809)

Comment: It does, but I've provided clarification on how to use it, which the author already knows

Comment: Thank you for this answer and I apologize for my late response. I understood the answer before the edit, however soon after I realized I needed a bit more work. I put some more details into my question to hopefully help others.