# What is the best way to check URL change with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, regex, selenium, url

So, what's I want to do is to run a function on a specific webpage (which is a match with my regex).

Right now I'm checking it every second and it works, but I'm sure that there is a better way (as it's flooding that website with getting requests).

```
while flag:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(driver.current_url)
    if driver.current_url == "mydesiredURL_by_Regex":
        time.sleep(1)
        myfunction()
```

I was thinking to do that somehow with `WebDriverWait` but not really sure how.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html), this is almost exactly what using WebDriverWait does. It checks a condition by default every 0.5s. One advantage is that using a single line with WebDriverWait is more readable than the >5 lines it would take with any other method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I was thinking to do that somehow with WebDriverWait

Exactly. First of all, see if the [built-in Expected Conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) may solve that:

- `title_is`
- `title_contains`

Sample usage:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_is("title"))
wait.until(EC.title_contains("part of title"))
```

If not, you can always create a [custom Expected Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848) to wait for url to match a desired regular expression.

Comment: got one more, a bit nooby question. is that timeout neccessary? I mean, maybe that script have to wait about 30 minutes for that expected condition/regex is there a good way to handle that too? thanks

Comment: @gyula from what I recall, the timeout is required..either set it to a large value, or use the "while true" approach..

Answer (score 18):

This is how I implemented it eventually. Works well for me:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
desired_url = "https://yourpageaddress"

def wait_for_correct_current_url(desired_url):
    wait.until(
        lambda driver: driver.current_url == desired_url)
```

Comment: This solution worked in my case.
current_url = 'https://www.yourpageaddress.com/auth/login/'
desired_url = 'https://www.yourpageaddress.com/'

Answer (score 6):

To really know that the URL has changed, you need to know the old one. Using `WebDriverWait` the implementation in Java would be something like:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe(oldUrl)));
```

I know the question is for Python, but it's probably easy to translate.

Comment: Actually, in Python you can use EC.url_changes(url) which returns True as soon as driver.current_url is not equal to url (anymore). So no need to negate EC.url_to_be.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using `WebdriverWait` with `expected_conditions`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

url = 'https://example.com/before'
changed_url = 'https://example.com/after'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# wait up to 10 secs for the url to change or else `TimeOutException` is raised.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_changes(changed_url))
```

Comment: For me it works with just waiting until the current URL changes, without needing to know the target URL: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_changes(driver.current_url))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `url_matches` [Link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#url_matches) to match a regex pattern with a url. It does `re.search(pattern, url)`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

pattern='https://www.example.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

wait.until(EC.url_matches(pattern))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used `while loop`

```py
prev_url = str(driver.current_url)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-cy="sidebar-game-over-new-game-button"]').click()
    while prev_url == str(driver.current_url):
        pass
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.