# selenium wait until html is reloaded

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script with python and selenium to scrape google results.. It works, but I'm looking for a better solution to wait until all `100` search results are fetched

I use this solution to wait until the search is done

```
driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.ID, 'resultStats')))
```

This works, but I need to get `100` search results so I do this

```
driver.get(driver.current_url+'&num=100')
```

But now its not possible to re-use this line because the element ID is already written to the page..

```
driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.ID, 'resultStats')))
```

Instead I use this solution, but its not a consistent solution (if the request takes more than 5 secs)

```
time.sleep(5)
```

## code

```
url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver.get(url)

try:
    box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.NAME, 'q')))
    box.send_keys(query.decode('utf-8'))
    button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.NAME, 'btnG')))
    button.click()
except TimeoutException:
    error('Box or Button not found in google.com')

try:
    driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, 'resultStats')))
    driver.get(driver.current_url+'&num=100')

    # Need a better solution to wait until all results are loaded
    time.sleep(5)

    print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf-8')
except TimeoutException:
    error('No results returned by Google. Could be HTTP 503 response')
```

Comment: is it possible to use multiprocessing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right that *`time.sleep(5)` is not a reliable and good way to wait for something on the page*. You would need to use [`WebDriverWait` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and a specific condition to wait for.

In this case, I'd wait for the count of elements with `class="g"` (which represents a search result) would be greater or equal to 100 via a [custom Expected Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377437/python-selenium-webdriver-writing-my-own-expected-condition/29377790#29377790):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_n_elements(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, count):
        self.locator = locator
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            count = len(EC._find_elements(driver, self.locator))
            return count >= self.count
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Usage:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(wait_for_n_elements((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g"), 100)
```