# Wait for page redirect Selenium WebDriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a page which loads dynamic content with ajax and then redirects after a certain amount of time (not fixed). How can I force Selenium Webdriver to wait for the page to redirect then go to a different link immediately after?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome();
driver.get("http://www.website.com/wait.php")
```

Comment: If you know the expected url you can use `driver.current_url` in a `while` loop.

Comment: You could wait for the URL to change with a waiter.

Answer (score 32):

You can create a custom [Expected Condition to wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the URL to change:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != "http://www.website.com/wait.php")
```

The Expected Condition is basically a *callable* - you can [wrap it into a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848) overwriting the `__call__()` magic method as the built-in conditions are implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put the second redirect url. Can you give me an example of how to wrap it in a class with the conditions provided?

Comment: @7O07Y7 in this expected condition we are just waiting for the current url to change. If you want to change it to wait for a specific url to be current, you can use `lambda driver: driver.current_url == "specific url"`..

Answer (score 25):

There are several [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) that can be used along with [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to handle page redirection:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

1. Wait for new page title with [`title_is(title_name)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_is):

   ```
   wait.until(EC.title_is('New page Title'))
   ```
2. Wait for current URL to be changed to any other URL with [`url_changes(exact_url)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_changes):

   ```
   wait.until(EC.url_changes('https://current_page.com'))
   ```
3. Wait for navigating to exact URL with [`url_to_be(exact_url)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_to_be):

   ```
   wait.until(EC.url_to_be('https://new_page.com'))
   ```

Also

[`url_contains(partial_url)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_contains) could be used to wait for URL that contains specified substring or [`url_matches(pattern)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_matches) - to wait for URL matched by passed regex pattern or [`title_contains(substring)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) - to wait for new title that contains specified substring

Answer (score 5):

It's a good practice to "wait" for unique (for new page) element to appear.

You may use module [expected_conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

For example, you could wait for user logo on signing in:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://yourapp.url')

timeout = 5

    try:
        logo_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'logo_id'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(logo_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (selenium v4.17), I just add `driver.implicitly_wait()` call :

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
```

as mentioned at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#implicit-waits