# Loading web page using headless Chrome and Selenium returns Debugging Information, IP Address Ray ID

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, bots

I am trying to create an application that scrapes certain e-commerce websites. I am using Selenium for this purpose and trying to deploy my application on an ec2 instance running centos. Before deploying, I developed my code locally and it worked but it gives me errors on the remote machine.

The code that I am using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

selenium_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.everlane.com/products/womens-cloud-cable-knit-vest-oatmeal?collection=womens-newest-arrivals'

selenium_driver.get(url)

title = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/hgroup/h1/span')
print(title.text)
```

When I try to run this code on remote machine I get an error with the following stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/price_tracker/flask_api.py", line 22, in home
    title, price, isSizeAvailable, shop = prices.checkInfoByShop(url, size)
  File "/home/ec2-user/price_tracker/check_prices.py", line 132, in checkInfoByShop
    secondaryPriceXPath=secondaryPriceXPath)
  File "/home/ec2-user/price_tracker/check_prices.py", line 61, in checkSelenium
    title = self.selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, titleXPath)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1246, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="content"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/hgroup/h1/span"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.110)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x559979e8dee3 <unknown>
#1 0x55997995b608 <unknown>
#2 0x559979991aa1 <unknown>
#3 0x559979991c61 <unknown>
#4 0x5599799c4714 <unknown>
#5 0x5599799af29d <unknown>
#6 0x5599799c23bc <unknown>
#7 0x5599799af163 <unknown>
#8 0x559979984bfc <unknown>
#9 0x559979985c05 <unknown>
#10 0x559979ebfbaa <unknown>
#11 0x559979ed5651 <unknown>
#12 0x559979ec0b05 <unknown>
#13 0x559979ed6a68 <unknown>
#14 0x559979eb505f <unknown>
#15 0x559979ef1818 <unknown>
#16 0x559979ef1998 <unknown>
#17 0x559979f0ceed <unknown>
#18 0x7ff5dd53b40b <unknown>
```

For debugging purposes, I tried to read the entire body of the webpage using

```
body = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body')
print(body.text)
```

which returns

```
"We're sorry, something has gone wrong. Please try again.\nIf you continue to have trouble, please contact us at support@everlane.com.\nChecking your browser before accessing www.everlane.com.\nThis process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.\nPlease allow up to 5 seconds…\nDebugging Information\nIP Address\n<ip-address>\nRay ID\n6c57184d797805a0"
```

I understand that my request might be getting blocked for some reason but is there a way to bypass this?

I have tried adding wait statements in the hope of landing on the redirect but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

That message looks like the page content has been changed. So your code is working as intended. I'd have Selenium wait for an element to be visible ([Read more here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)). If you don't want to do that you can also wait for the page to redirect. How to do that is answered in [another SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002826/wait-for-page-redirect-selenium-webdriver-python/41725576).

Comment: I have tried adding wait statements but it does not help, no matter how long I wait for.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the message:

```
Checking your browser before accessing www.everlane.com.
This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.
```

This site seems to have Cloudfare protection enabled. See the [reference](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-fix-checking-your-browser-before-accessing-message/).

I suggest to try [`selenium-stealth`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium_stealth import stealth

ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

url = 'https://www.everlane.com/products/womens-cloud-cable-knit-vest-oatmeal?collection=womens-newest-arrivals'

driver.get(url)
title = selenium_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/hgroup/h1/span')
print(title.text)
```

Some of these repositories might be helpful:

- [`undetected-chromedriver`](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)
- [`cloudscraper`](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper)
- [`pupflare`](https://github.com/unixfox/pupflare)

Or look at this [topic](https://github.com/topics/cloudflare-bypass).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using webdriver waits to wait for the page to load.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,selenium_driver)                                 
elem=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id="content"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/hgroup/h1/span")))
print(elem.text)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This message...

```
"We're sorry, something has gone wrong. Please try again.\nIf you continue to have trouble, please contact us at support@everlane.com.\nChecking your browser before accessing www.everlane.com.\nThis process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.\nPlease allow up to 5 seconds…\nDebugging Information\nIP Address\n<ip-address>\nRay ID\n6c57184d797805a0"
```

...implies that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* was detected as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot).

---

However, I was able to bypass the detection through [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) using a few arguments as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.everlane.com/products/womens-cloud-cable-knit-vest-oatmeal?collection=womens-newest-arrivals")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='product-heading__name']/span"))).text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  The Cloud Cable-Knit Vest
  ```