# Python/Selenium - Execute a code when the URL change

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to get all the inputs with a particular class when the user change or refresh the URL.

```
getInputs = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "slds-input")
getInputs.send_keys("Test")
```

The problem is that this code is only executed in the actual page, but it dosn't execute when a user navigate to another page so if anyone knows a function or something which execute a code everytime the URL change, it will be quite helpful, Thank you!

Comment: How are you tracking the url changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for page redirect Selenium WebDriver (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002826/wait-for-page-redirect-selenium-webdriver-python)