# How to wait for presence of an element with non empty content?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

How can I wait for a presence of an element which the content (text) is not empty? I tried select by xpath using `//*[@id="test" and text() != ""]`, but the return of `WebDriverWait#until` does not retrieve the element.

My code:

```
selector = '//*[@id="test" and text() != ""]'
element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
  expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, selector))
)
```

I would like to get the text content of the element. I tried:

```
print element.text # prints 0
```

If i print only `element`, the output is `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="xxx", element="xxx")>`. What is wrong?

The div I'm tryin to get has this structure:

```html
<div>
   Test:
   <div id="test"><b>this text here</b></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wait for an element by xpath with non empty text like this:

```
xpath = "//*[@id='test']"

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text.strip() != '')
```

[source](https://codeinpython.blogspot.com/2018/11/python-how-to-wait-for-presence-of.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `text()` xpath function would not help in this case since it would not consider the texts of the child elements. You actually need to call the `.text` in your Expected Condition. [You can create a custom one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19377437/771848):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_non_empty_text(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text.strip()
            return element_text != ""
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Usage:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
element = wait.until(
    wait_for_non_empty_text((By.ID, "test"))
)
print(element.text)
```

Comment: @renan hm, should not be the case if you copied the code correctly, please recheck.

Comment: @renan could you please put a `print(element_text)` into the Expected Condition to see what the value is printed. Also, is there a difference if you would use `element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).get_attribute("textContent").strip()` instead? Thanks.

Comment: @renan oh yeah, try without calling `strip()` please.

Comment: I put a print to show `element_text` value and it's `0`.

Comment: @renan ah, so, do you need to wait for the text to be non-zero or non-empty?

Comment: Non empty alecxe, but the return of `EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text.strip()` is being `0` and don't know from where this value is comming, the page does not insert `0` inside the div `#test`.

Comment: @alecxe, this was a great tip I used successfully in my work, but after upgrade to Selenium 4, there is no longer _find_element() function in expected_conditions, so your wait_for_non_empty_text no longer works. Is there a way to change it to still be able to call this function using wait.until() in Selenium 4 please?